# I get a status 200 when connecting to the websocket, but it is an error?

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, websocket, spring-websocket

My error shows up in the console of my browser:

`"WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:32768/DspClusterWebServices/myHandler' failed: Unexpected response code: 200"`

I am using `Spring Websockets 4.1.5` and `Tomcat 8.0.18`. My WebSocketConfigurer implementation class looks like:

```
@Configuration
@Controller
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer
{
   class MyHandler implements WebSocketHandler
   {
      @Override
      public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception
      {
         System.out.println("afterConntectionEstablished called");
      }

       ...implements rest of functions with a System.out.println and false for supportsPartialMessages()

      }
   }

   @Override registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry)
   {
      registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "myHandler").withSockJS();
   }

   @Bean
   public WebSocketHandler myHandler()
   {
      return new MyHandler();
   }
}
```

My testWebsocketClient.js tries to connect with this code, but has a error code of 200:

```
websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/myApp/myHandler");
```

I cannot figure out what to try next. I thought that this would cause the afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) method to fire? Isn't code 200 good?

Comment: take a look at this, plz http://stackoverflow.com/a/14555549/592355 in particular: "As for your "Unexpected response code: 200" error, I'm guessing that the WebSocket URL you're using on the client side is not pointing to a valid server-side script, but that's hard to comment on without more info."

Comment: What information is needed? I am using Tomcat 8.0.18 and I can see the websocket-api.jar and tomcat-websocket.jar in the lib folder of the Tomcat installation...

Comment: How about the Controller annotation? (It is not in WebSocket samples)...dont you think that could interfere?

Comment: Removing the @Controller had no effect, I still get an error code of 200

Comment: hummm...[this](http://procbits.com/connecting-to-a-sockjs-server-from-native-html5-websocket) sounds good: please try to connect to "ws://localhost:8080/myApp/myHandler/websocket" !?

Comment: xerx593 please make an answer containing that link and also with this link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2586

After I added websocket, it gave me the error "Failed to parse Origin header value [null]", which then lead me to that link. I had to add .setAllowedOrigins("*") to my addHandler() method. Then it finally worked!

If you make the answer I will check it so you get the credit you deserve

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Please check http://procbits.com/connecting-to-a-sockjs-server-from-native-html5-websocket!

After you append `/websocket` (to your URL), it will give you the error

> Failed to parse Origin header value [null]

;)
, which then will in turn lead you to [that link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2586).

You'll  have to add `.setAllowedOrigins("*")` to your `addHandler()` method, and then it could finally work!

Comment: Just as an add-on, if you remove the .withSockJs() call off the server and the /websocket off the client code, it will work that way too! Tricky stuff, hopefully this helps people in the future! Thanks again xerx593 for helping me find a solution!

Comment: Oh my GOD！！！！Really thanks！！！ This problem has troubled me for 3 hours....

Comment: I wasted 3 days ! and this works. WoW ! Thanks !

Answer (score 19):

As my another answer:[https://stackoverflow.com/a/53272666/2930417][1]

I use springboot 2 +STOMP。

remove `.withSockJS()`,then everything is ok.

I don't know the reason,but works for me.

Comment: I followed the official tutorial of https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ and add .withSockJS(). Removing it helped since I only want to use the library StompJS in my case

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) . The server should respond with `101` to signal protocol change from `http` to `ws`.

Comment: I am still not sure what to do, this link gives further explanation of the status 200 code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190644/what-does-websocket-upgrade-request-failed-exception-mean-in-a-context-of-web

Something must be wrong on the server end, but I am not sure how, I am using Tomcat 8.0.18

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if this is too late but a solution that I stumbled upon is simply appending the string `/websocket` after the websocket endpoint that you declared in the spring boot server. This will help keep both the forwarding logic and connect and establish a websocket connection.

Answer (score 4):

For those guys like me who use angular + springboot and got this error. please check if you have enabled the redirect or forward all non api endpoint request back to index.html. like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String redirect() {
        // Forward to home page so that route is preserved.
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }
```

If you do, disable it and you will get 101

Comment: And what to do if I need both the redirect() method and the websocket?

Comment: @Gleb 
put all the route path you defined at angular level in the value array. for example, you defined "/login", "/logout" and "/welcome" routes in app.module.ts, and you also have some restful calls starting with "api". then you need to modify the annotation like @RequestMapping(value = {"/login", "/logout", "/welcome", "/api/**"})

Comment: @forguta by just delete your websocket handler...?

Comment: This helped me: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9591. (I'm using jhipster)

Answer (score 2):

Please check that if 'ws://localhost:32768/DspClusterWebServices/myHandler' is correct.