# Socket.io code 200 Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: socket.io, apache2

I am using **socket.io** with nodejs and an **apache** server over it.
I am getting a code **200** as response, I know I must get **101**.

> WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://SITEABC.com/socket.io/?siteId=site1234567&EIO=3&transport=websocket'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line

The configuration on apache is the folowing:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} ^Websocket [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:1337/{REQUEST_URI} [P]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

ProxyPass / http://localhost:1337/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1337/
ProxyPass /socket.io/ http://localhost:1337/socket.io/
```

Node is running on port 1337

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 5):

I use springboot 2 + stomp.
In my case ,the reason is in WebSocketConfig,must remove `.withSockJS`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .addInterceptors(new HandshakeInterceptor())

                //--> important must remove,or 200 error.
                //.withSockJS()

                ;
    }
```

Comment: after that , everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

This means your requests are not being proxied to your WebSocket handler, but for some other route which returns a 200.

You should check your WebSocket handler.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: In my case, the WebSocket request protocol for the requests were changed from ws:// to http:// which avoided requests being routed to the specific WebSocket handler on the backend

Comment: I have a NodeJS server running on http://localhost:8082 which is meant to handle Websocket calls.  It can't start sending ws:// etc  calls until the handshake is complete.  The handshake wont complete until a 101 status line is returned.  its certainly receiving the requests because it falls back to Ajax when it can't complete the handshake.

Comment: Falls back to Ajax..Yes. But it’s actually the socket.io library on client side which makes the Ajax call.. because it couldn’t complete the WebSocket handshake..

Comment: Yes I understand that part,  sorry the way I phrased it made it sound like the server was doing Ajax calls.   The problem was with the ProxyPass I was doing.  I decided to pull the Node server out from behind the Apache server and to just have the app make calls to the Node server on a different port.  The issue is fixed :)

Comment: That’s Awesome! 