# WebSocket working on local, AWS but not on AliBaba cloud

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, cloud, alibaba-cloud

We've a pretty straight WebSocket node.js implementation which is working fine on

- our local machines.
- AWS cloud

but not working on

- Alibaba cloud

All the http/https requests are hitting but the websocket requests are not.

Tried to find the RCA of this:

- [Google Chromium browser specific support issue](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/979#issuecomment-276879618)
- [Issue with Google App Engine](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/issues/237#issuecomment-296676068)
- [Some deleted stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025073/error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-400-with-nginx-proxy)
- [All ports are open in our case](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/455#issuecomment-299243075), and [we're not using Socket.io also](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/455#issuecomment-299385827)
- [Code is not the problem for us](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/issues/252)
- Don't know if [Alibaba blocks 8000/tcp ports](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/543#issuecomment-328305403)
- [We're too not sure why it's not working with Websockets](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-create-agent/issues/151#issuecomment-301793157)
- [CORS is enabled with the node server app already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829597/i-get-a-status-200-when-connecting-to-the-websocket-but-it-is-an-error)

Not very sure if [Alibaba cloud supports WebSockets](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/51500.htm) also.

Any more kind suggestions please?

Comment: Which service are you using, Elastic Computing Service, can you describe more about "not working", any error message?

Comment: @JeffreyChen It's not even hitting the instance. All the http requests are hitting but the websocket requests are not hitting

Comment: have you checked the security group to allow TCP 80 port?

Answer (score 1):

We implemented WebSocket successfully for both AWS and Alibaba Cloud. WebSocket requires proper SSL termination, AWS/local and Alibaba Cloud have different locations for https/SSL settings depending on your application architecture. You can read the "WebSocket support" in the following Alibaba Cloud document to find out more details:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/50309.htm

The AWS guide is: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-build-a-chat-application-with-amazon-elasticache-for-redis/